# Create Excel File to External Low Storage ThumbDrive by Using DocumentFormat Open XML

Tags: c#, asp.net

[https://ibb.co/dKZJMk] This link is the image that show unhandled IO exception even though i have implemented IO Exception handler. The E means E drive which is low storage external hard drive.

Any expertise encounter this issue? Continuous to create and write excel file to insufficient storage ThumbDrive by using Open XML DLL it will cause the program shutdown even though the IO Exception is handled. I have search through internet cannot find any answer of this i'm wondering is it the Open XML DLL issue. I can provide the sample code if needed.

```
    private static void CreateExcelFile(string drive)
    {
        try
        {

            using (SpreadsheetDocument workBook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(string.Format(@"{0}:\Dummy{1}.xlsx", drive, DateTime.Now.Millisecond), SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                OpenXmlWriter writer;

                WorkbookPart workbookPart = workBook.AddWorkbookPart();
                workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
                Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

                //Creating the worksheetPart
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();

                //Adding the sheet to the workbookpart
                sheets.Append(new Sheet() { Id = workBook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "sht" });

                writer = OpenXmlWriter.Create(worksheetPart);
                writer.WriteStartElement(new Worksheet());
                writer.WriteStartElement(new SheetData());

                writer.WriteStartElement(new Row());


                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    Cell cell = new Cell();
                    cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(i.ToString());
                    cell.CellReference = new StringValue(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}" + 1, GetExcelColumnReference(i + 1)));

                    //Start tag for writing a cell
                    writer.WriteStartElement(cell);
                    writer.WriteElement(cell.CellValue);
                    //End tag for writing a cell
                    writer.WriteEndElement();

                }

                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.Close();
                workBook.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IO Error");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("General Error");
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide sample code and try to be more specific in your question. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question to make sure you get the answer you need. Good luck!

Comment: Providing sample code may help anyone figuring out what problem you have, I recommend you to do so. Without any example code what you've requested here is still very broad topic.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto thanks for the tips. I have uploaded the image and sample code as well if you use the same sample code and create a file on insufficient external disk it will have the same issue like the image i shared. Hope i can get back from you soon.